# New ODBC issue Access 2007

Tags: vba, ms-access, sql-server-2008-r2, odbc

I have an MS Access 2007 front end to a MS SQL Server 2008R2 back end.

I've got a query that's part of a loop, and it's suddenly started generating `Run-time error '3146': ODBC--call failed.` errors on one query as the loop itterates. Oddly, it's not the first iteration.  EDIT: When I say suddenly, it's been running like this just fine for several months (probably since March).

```
Set db = CurrentDb
db.QueryTimeout = 480 'thought there was a timeout issue, so set this very high
    Set SupvRS = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT tblProcessors.Supervisor, tblProcessors.SupervisorEmail " & _
        "  FROM tblProcessors INNER JOIN (tblAuditPr INNER JOIN tblAuditPr_A ON tblAuditPr.PrAudit_ID = tblAuditPr_A.PrAudit_ID)" & _
                            " ON tblProcessors.Processor = tblAuditPr_A.Processor" & _
        " WHERE tblProcessors.Supervisor IS NOT NULL " & _
        "   AND tblAuditPr.EndDate BETWEEN " & GetSQLDate(Me.txtFrom) & " AND " & GetSQLDate(Me.txtTo) & _
        "   AND tblProcessors.Processor<>'Default Processor' " & _
        "   AND tblAuditPr_A.Answer Not In ('NA','NF')" & _
        "   AND tblAuditPr.Status = 'Submitted'")
    Do While Not SupvRS.EOF
        'Send Supervisor Email
        Attachment = PARG.GenerateAuditReport(SupvRS.Fields("Supervisor"), parSupervisor, Me.txtFrom, Me.txtTo)
        Set EmailRS = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblProcessors WHERE Supervisor = " & GetSQLString(SupvRS.Fields("Supervisor")))
        If EmailRS.EOF Then
            Err.Raise -234923, Description:="Cannot find tblProcessors record for " & SupvRS.Fields("Supervisor") & "."
        End If
        If IsNull(EmailRS.Fields("SupervisorEmail")) Then
            MailTo = <redacted>
        Else
            MailTo = EmailRS.Fields("SupervisorEmail")
        End If
        Set EmailRS = Nothing
        Mailer.AddMailDocument MailTo:=MailTo, _
            Subject:=Subject, _
            Body:=Body, _
            Attachments:=Attachment, _
            From:=<redacted>
        'Iterate processor emails if requested.
        If Me.chkProcessor Then
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'ERROR occurs here, but only after several supervisors have successfully passed through
            Set ProcRS = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT tblProcessors.Processor, tblProcessors.ProcessorEmail FROM tblAuditPr" & _
                " INNER JOIN (tblProcessors INNER JOIN tblAuditPr_A ON tblProcessors.Processor = tblAuditPr_A.Processor) " & _
                " ON tblAuditPr.PrAudit_ID = tblAuditPr_A.PrAudit_ID" & _
                " WHERE tblProcessors.Supervisor = " & GetSQLString(SupvRS.Fields("Supervisor")) & _
                " AND tblAuditPr.EndDate BETWEEN " & GetSQLDate(Me.txtFrom) & " AND " & GetSQLDate(Me.txtTo))
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            Do While Not ProcRS.EOF
                If Not IsNull(ProcRS.Fields("ProcessorEmail")) Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Attachment = PARG.GenerateAuditReport(ProcRS.Fields("Processor"), parProcessor, Me.txtFrom, Me.txtTo)
                    If Attachment <> "" Then
                        MailTo = ProcRS.Fields("ProcessorEmail")
                        Mailer.AddMailDocument MailTo:=MailTo, _
                            Subject:=Subject, _
                            Body:=Body, _
                            Attachments:=Attachment, _
                            From:=<redacted>
                    Else
                        Err.Clear
                    End If
                    On Error GoTo 0
                End If
                ProcRS.MoveNext
            Loop
            Set ProcRS = Nothing
        End If
        SupvRS.MoveNext
    Loop
```

As noted in the code, the error occurs on an inner loop that successfully executes for other supervisors. It does consistantly break on one particular individual. Using the `GetSQLString` and `GetSQLDate` functions (returns ' delimited, double '' when necessary, pretty strings, and # delimited dates, respectivly, for passing Access queries through to SQL Server) in break mode, I duplicated the exact query that was giving me problems in an Access query. It returned a timeout error, but changing the database default timeout (and closing/opening the db) didn't resolve the issue. I pasted the exact same query into SSMS (replacing the # date delimiters with ') and it executed just fine there (taking about 1:30-2:00 to execute each try).

Taking a pause in typing up this post, I put some error trapping in to see if I could get the actual error message SQL Server was returning, when it ran without error. To me, that indicates that it is likely a time out issue. Anyone have a more educated guess as to what it actually is, or a suggestion on how to make the query more efficient so it doesn't time out?

Comment: Yuck.. DAO. Any reason you aren't using ADO?

Comment: Run your first query against the sql server by hand using SSMS. Does it return any rows where Supervisor is NULL?

Comment: This project is a mixture of DAO, ADO, Stored Procedure calls, and other random bits as they've been added.  Would changing to ADO buy me anything significant in this particular instance.

Comment: There are no NULL results in the outer loop query. It was failing on one specific supervisor each time it failed, but did run successfully (with the same date range), finally.

Comment: It's hard to tell. 3146 is generic... going to ADO may get you a more exact error. Also, have you tried implementing something like this: `On Error GoTo ErrCatch /
ErrCatch: /
Dim theError As Error /
For Each theError In DBEngine.Errors /
MsgBox "Error: " & theError.Number & vbCr & theError.Description /
Next theError`

Comment: As I went to implement very similar code, it executed without error, so I haven't seen exactly what SQL Server was returning.

Comment: No way to get the test case back?

Comment: It only seems to have failed this one particular day, and now it appears to be working again. I've created a view on the Server, and selecting the required data from it takes 1 second or less, so I'm going to implement that into code to see if this goes away and never comes back.

Comment: I notice that you do not do a `ProcRS.Close` before `Set ProcRS = Nothing`. It certainly would be good form to explicitly `.Close` the RecordSet object before sending it to oblivion.

Comment: Why recommend ADO when Microsoft recommend DAO for use with MS Access? For example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164825(v=office.10).aspx, I can provide other references that show the speed differences between native DAO and ADO if you wish. Microsoft has even abandoned ADP in favour of linked tables.

Comment: @GordThompson thanks for the suggestion. I've closed the queries before nulling them. Not sure how critical it is, but it is nice and tidy.